# Kubeflow Notebook: connect to SQL Server

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, mssql-jdbc, kubeflow

I'm using kuberflow notebook (python 3) and trying to connect to my sql server. So far here's my code:

```
import jaydebeapi
driver_name = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
connection_url = f"jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server_address"
connection_properties = {
    "user": 'username',
    "password": 'password',
    "domain": "USER"
}
jar_path = '/home/jovyan/jtds-1.3.1.jar'
connection = jaydebeapi.connect(driver_name, connection_url, connection_properties, jar_path)
```

and I receive a `TypeError: Class net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver is not found`

I've tried the following:

- Uploaded the jar file right next to the notebook
- Change jar_path to '/jtds-1.3.1.jar', '/user-vol-1/jtds-1.3.1.jar'

Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

managed to solved it by changing `jar_path = '/home/jovyan/user-vol-1/jtds-1.3.1.jar'`

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).